# If current user of Excel workbook is not in Array then hide columns ("O:P")

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, hide, worksheet-function

I have a Array of users of a workbook that I want if the username is not in my Array then `columns (O:P)`  must be hidden.

I got a Type Mismatch error and have no idea what the problem is.
Thanks

Here is my code:

```
userlist = Array("user1", "user2", "user3", "user4")
If Application.UserName <> userlist Then
Worksheets("Master").Range("O:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple approaches to check the existence of a username.

1. for loop

```
userlist = Array("user1", "user2", "user3", "user4")
bFound = False
For i = LBound(userlist) To UBound(userlist)
   If userlist(i) = Application.UserName Then
      bFound = True
      Exit For
   End If
Next
If Not bFound Then _
  Worksheets("Master").Range("O:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

2. instr

```
userlist = Array("user1", "user2", "user3", "user4")
strUserlist = "|" & Join(userlist, "|") & "|"
strUser = "|" & Application.UserName & "|"
If InStr(1, strUserlist, strUser) = 0 Then _
  Worksheets("Master").Range("O:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

3. Filter

```
userlist = Array("user1", "user2", "user3", "user4")
strUser = Application.UserName
If UBound(Filter(userlist, strUser)) = -1 Then _
  Worksheets("Master").Range("O:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Comment: I hope you are assuming that OP knows to put `Option Explicit` at the top of each module and declare all variables. Also, that's really a horrible way to write the *If* statements. In **1**, to enforce case insensitivity, you could use `If StrComp(userlist(i), Application.UserName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then Exit For`. Also, storing the user name in a variable should be considered since we're in a loop. There is also a *For...Next* loop 'trick', to simplify by getting rid of the boolean variable: `If i > Ubound(userList) Then`...

Comment: ... In **2**, you need to correct `strUserlist = "|" & Join(userlist, "|") & "|"`. Again, to enforce case insensitivity, you could use: `If InStr(1, strUserlist, strUser, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then`. In **3**, again, to enforce case insensitivity, you could use `If UBound(Filter(userlist, strUser, , vbTextCompare)) = -1 Then` or the safer (*Option Base* related): `Dim arr: arr = Filter(userlist, strUser, , vbTextCompare): If UBound(arr) < LBound(arr) Then`.

Comment: @VBasic2008, It is just a code snippet. I don't think it is necessary to add "Option Explicit" on all posts.
"Enforce case insensitivity" is not alway the best solution. The user names might be case sensitive in some systems.

Comment: The only mistake in your snippets is `Join(userlist)`. The rest of my comments are supposed to be educational e.g. about declaring all variables (they are all variants in your snippets) and thinking about case sensitivity (If you know a user name, why would you care if it's `USER1`, `user1`, or `UsEr1` when writing it to a list (array)? All your snippets will fail if the case is not correct.). Also, the final *If* statements are correct but are, IMO, in a horrible format. Note that I have also used this format in some of my answers but have abandoned it since I think it's less readable.

Comment: @VBasic2008 You are right. I have corrected "Join(userlist)" in my post. 

Could you kindly share your perspective on the correct usage of the "If" statement?Thanks.

Comment: There is no correct or incorrect, it's about readability. If you always write your If statements this way, keep doing it. I prefer `If...Then...End If` (three lines), rarely `If...Then...` in a single line (if they fit (I don't like to have lines longer than 80 characters)), both used by most SO contributors.

Comment: Got it. Each person may have their own preferred choice for the most favorite cookie.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the code tries to test whether a string is equal to an array of strings. Strings and arrays are different data types, and that produces the error.

If you want to test whether a string is equal to any of the strings in an array, this is a common method:

```
userlist = Array("user1", "user2", "user3", "user4")
  If UBound(Filter(userlist, Application.UserName)) > -1 Then
  Worksheets("Master").Range("O:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  End If
```

`Filter` will filter the array to items that match `UserName`.

If the filtered array has one matching item, `UBound` will equal 0. If the filtered array has no matching items, `UBound` will equal -1.

Answer (score 1):

### Is User Name Found in Array (`Application.Match`)?

```vb
Dim UserList(): UserList = Array("user1", "user2", "user3", "user4")

If IsError(Application.Match(Application.UserName, UserList, 0)) Then
    Worksheets("Master").Columns("O:P").Hidden = True
End If
```